# jQuery.load using POST instead of GET

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

I have very simple code as below:

```
function AjaxDialog(title, url) {
    var window = $('<div title="' + title + '"></div>');
    window
        .appendTo('body')
        .dialog();

    window.load(url, function () {
            window
                .dialog({ width: "auto", height: "auto" })
                .dialog("option", "position", "center");
        });

    return window;
}
```

The `window.load` has been using a GET for months (using jQuery 1.6.4) but since I upgraded jQuery to version 1.10.1 it has started using POST. Any idea why?

Comment: Request Method

The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: What data is being posted?

Comment: If you need a GET request, and `load()` is using POST, you can always use `$.get` instead.

Comment: @Matt I read that in the jQuery.load documentation but don't understand what data is being provided as an object in my case to cause the `POST` method to be used.

Comment: @Travesty3 The only data being posted might be a variable or two in the querystring section of the `url` parameter e.g. if the url was `/MyController/MyAction/MyId?a=1&b=2`

Comment: @Jimbo Can you take out the callback and test to see if it uses GET after that.

Comment: @Matt Just tried now, but it still uses POST :(

Comment: @Jimbo I was thinking there may be a bug, try this anyway. Do window.load(url, null, function()...);

Comment: @Jimbo: Can you reproduce your problem in a jsFiddle? [I tried](http://jsfiddle.net/JmR2c/), but it's using GET for me (in Chrome, open the dev console and watch the Network tab).

Comment: @Matt Sorry for the delay, sadly still using POST even with null specified for the `data` parameter.

Comment: I have changed the method to use `$.get()` and that's working fine for now peeps. Thank you all for your input thus far.